# How to change the particular letter color in text box using python

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-2, qt-designer, pyqt4

I need to highlight the particular letter in a text box using Python.

I am using the below code but it changes the entire text color in text box.

Can you suggest any other ideas?

I am using both **QlineEdit** and **QTextEdit** objects.

```
 if self.dlgAttribute.ui.txtPartDesc3.text()!="":
    partDescValue = self.dlgAttribute.ui.txtPartDesc3.text()
    if not partDescValue in self.englishArray:
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.dlgAttribute.ui.txtPartDesc3.setFont(font)
        self.dlgAttribute.ui.txtPartDesc3.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("color: rgb(255, 162, 0);\n"
        "background-color: rgb(41, 91, 170);\n"
        "font: 750 10pt \"Arial\";"))
    else:
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.dlgAttribute.ui.txtPartDesc3.setFont(font)
        self.dlgAttribute.ui.txtPartDesc3.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("color: rgb(0,0,0);\n"
        "background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
        "font: 750 10pt \"Arial\";"))
else:
    font.setPointSize(11)
    self.dlgAttribute.ui.txtPartDesc3.setFont(font)
    self.dlgAttribute.ui.txtPartDesc3.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("color: rgb(0,0,0);\n"
    "background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
    "font: 750 10pt \"Arial\";"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an HTML declaration to change the text color inside a text box.

An example is given on the following link: [color in a qt text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23324211/how-do-i-set-text-colour-in-qtextbrowser-html-pyqt)

And here is an example of how to change only one letter: [one letter color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341670/change-color-of-one-character-in-a-text-box-html-css)